# jQuery Ajax Form Not Working with Select Elements

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms

I seem to be having a strange issue with jQuery and a newly-created AJAX form/function. I'm pretty new to AJAX so please bear with me. Here's the jQuery:

```
jQuery('#wpuf_new_post_form').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var data2 = jQuery('#wpuf_new_post_form').serialize();

    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: data2 + '&action=savedata',
        success: function(resp) {
            if(!resp){ alert ('Failed!')}else{ alert(data2) }
        }
    });

});
```

The above code takes the submission of my `#wpuf_new_post_form` form, serializes the data, then passes it through to my PHP function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_savedata', 'my_ajax_save_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_savedata', 'my_ajax_save_form');

function my_ajax_save_form(){

    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $_POST['wpuf_post_title'],
        'post_content'  => $_POST['wpuf_post_content'],
        'post_type'     => $_POST['wpuf_post_type'],
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    );

    wp_insert_post($my_post);

    $this_post_ID = wp_insert_post($my_post);

    add_post_meta($this_post_ID, 'cf_user-timestamp',  $_POST['cf_user-timestamp']);
    add_post_meta($this_post_ID, 'cf_project-id',  $_POST['cf_project-id']);
    add_post_meta($this_post_ID, 'cf_bin-id',  $_POST['cf_bin-id']);
    add_post_meta($this_post_ID, 'cf_status',  $_POST['cf_status']);
    add_post_meta($this_post_ID, 'cf_schedule-date',  $_POST['cf_schedule-date']);
    add_post_meta($this_post_ID, 'cf_reply-url',  $_POST['cf_reply-url']);
    add_post_meta($this_post_ID, 'cf_from-user',  $_POST['cf_from-user']);

}
```

Creating the post and post meta as shown above, via the AJAX submission, works just fine. The only three fields which refuse to work happen to be `select` form elements.

They are:

- cf_project-id
- cf_bin-id
- cf_status

Again, all the other post meta submissions as depicted above, hit the database just fine. It's only the `select` form element values that do not.

Is there possibly a better way to handle the serialized value of `select` form elements?

**PS:** If it's of any value, here's an example of the serialized string that's being passed through as the jQuery variable `data2`. As you can see, the format doesn't differ from any of the other submitted form elements:

`_wpnonce=537e4539cc&_wp_http_referer=%2Fajax%2F&wpuf_post_title=1395254005136&wpuf_post_content=Testing&cf_user-timestamp=March+19th+2014%2C+11%3A33%3A25+am&cf_project-id=3797&cf_bin-id=3325&cf_status=-status-today&cf_schedule-date=03%2F21%2F2014&cf_reply-url=&cf_from-user=&wpuf_post_type=post&wpuf_post_new_submit=yes`

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: You understand that everything after `return false` is never processed ?

Comment: @adeneo Seems to work just fine with or without the return false since the wp_insert_post() function is working properly, but I've removed just for the sake of simplicity. Problem persists.

Comment: @Bene Sorry, html is dynamically created via a plugin and would be a bit long and messy to post here. Is there a specific part you would like to look at? I could post a portion of it here.

Comment: I would like to the form, espescially the select that won't work

Answer (score 0):

see if you have added 'name' attribute for select element in the html that might be the problem.

Comment: Yep, each of the select elements have an associated name attribute: name="cf_project-id", name="cf_bin-id", name="cf_status"